# Angularjs $scope.$watchCollection first level properties only

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When `$scope.$watchCollection` is  used for changes of properties in a object, it evaluates first level properties only. Is there a way to force angular to evaluate the second level or lower level when the `$scope.$watchCollection` is called ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `$scope.$watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]);` Where the third argument, "objectEquality", is `true`

> - The watchExpression is called on every call to `$digest()` and should return the value that will be watched. (Since `$digest()` reruns when it
>     detects changes the watchExpression can execute multiple times per
>     `$digest()` and should be idempotent.)
> - The listener is called only when the value from the current `watchExpression` and the previous call to `watchExpression` are not equal
>     (with the exception of the initial run, see below). Inequality is
>     determined according to reference inequality, strict comparison via
>     the `!==` Javascript operator, unless `objectEquality == true` (see next
>     point)
> - When `objectEquality == true`, inequality of the `watchExpression` is determined according to the `angular.equals` function. To save the value
>     of the object for later comparison, the `angular.copy` function is used.
>     This therefore means that watching complex objects will have adverse
>     memory and performance implications. The watch listener may change the
>     model, which may trigger other listeners to fire. This is achieved by
>     rerunning the watchers until no changes are detected. The rerun
>     iteration limit is 10 to prevent an infinite loop deadlock.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch